# Boas práticas para um Model que interage com 2 tabelas?

Tags: php, mvc

Estou construíndo uma aplicação MVC, para ser mais exato para envio de mensagens SMS, e me deparei com a seguinte situação: Possuo o **smsModel** que é responsável, principalmente,por enviar, agendar, cancelar o envio dos SMS, e ele possui uma tabela padrão que estão algumas informações, por exemplo, preço por envio unitário, preço para envio múltiplo e etc, basicamente todos os métodos que interagem com o banco de dados usam essa tabela, porém existe um método responsável por salvar um histórico de envio e ele usa outra tabela, e gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática alterar o nome da tabela dentro do próprio método que faz esse histórico ou criar um **Model** somente para esssa finalidade, a estrutura basicamente é essa:

```
abstract class Model {

    protected function create (array $data) {

        $create_table = $this->table_name;
        //insere no banco
    }

}

class smsModel extends Model {

    private $table_name = 'sms_config';
    private $log_table_name = 'sms_log';

    public function create (array $data) {

        return parent::create($data);
    }

    public function create_sms_log (array $data) {
        $this->table_name = $this->log_table_name;
        return parent::create($data);

    }

}
```